# Set the max value of the right axis variable

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization, axis

Is there any possibilities to set the max value of the right axis on Google Sheet variable? For example, the value of a particular cell (G2 in this case).

[image]

If not, can I set the min and max value as the same as the left axis?

Comment: if it's possible then only via script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes,it is possible by means of [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Here a sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range=sheet.getRange('A1:B5');
  var Xmax=sheet.getRange('G12').getValue();

  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(range)
      .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
  .setOption('hAxis', {
  viewWindow: {
    max:Xmax,
    min:0
  }
})
    .setPosition(5,5,1,1)
    .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

[setOption](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/column-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object)) allows you to use [advanced configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), such as specifying the `viewWindow`. Here you can assign to the maximum value the content of a particular cell, as done in the sample code. Make sure that the cell value is a valid integer.